# Google analytics doesn't work on my heroku app

Tags: heroku, google-analytics, subdomain

I run a python web app on heroku platform,

using heroku sub domain like: `example.herokuapp.com`

and I add `google analytics` js code to my page:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'herokuapp.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I have insert this script over 12 hours, but when I enter my ga account admin panel, it tell me:

> The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your
>   website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web
>   administrator must add the code to each page of your website.

however, I still can see some PV on the report panel

Does the ga work or not? How can I solve this problem? If I use a top level domain could solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check whether the analytics javascript is displayed when hitting "view source" on you page in the a browser?

Comment: @friism: I'm sure, and I check the chrome develop network panel, the ga request had been deliver

Comment: would you please mind sharing how you set up your Google Analytics on Heroku. I'm struggling in doing that due to the lack of sources... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800454/set-up-google-analytics-tracking-code-on-heroku this is the link to my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things regarding your `ga.create()` call:

1) The third parameter ("`herokuapp.com`" in your case) is supposed to be a Javascript object, not a plain string. Did you actually mean `{'cookieDomain': 'herokuapp.com'}`?

2) If you did... then it should be `example.herokuapp.com` -- you can't set a cookie on all of `herokuapp.com`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the new universal analytics is actually a little slow to kick in within the interface. The old Google analytics used to be like this and could take a day to work.

I have set up universal analytics on 6 sites now, I could see the calls being made to google but it took a day for data to show.

Have you used any debugging tools available.

For Firefox httpfox is a great tool, once installed select start and filter by 'collect' this will display analytics calls if they are working.

In chrome there are 2 good extensions, tag assistant and ga debug both by Google. Both of these can help identify implementation issues.

Hope this helps

John

Answer (score 0):

Credit: https://towardsdatascience.com/advancing-to-professional-dashboard-with-python-using-dash-and-plotly-1e8e5aa4c668#cf77
Try this

```
import dash

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.index_string = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-131327483-1"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', 'UA-131327483-1');
        </script>
        {%metas%}
        <title>{%title%}</title>
        {%favicon%}
        {%css%}
    </head>
    <body>
        {%app_entry%}
        <footer>
            {%config%}
            {%scripts%}
            {%renderer%}
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>"""
```